# Processing SQLite files using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, open-source-gis, arcgis-9.3, ogr, sqlite

I'm using qgis and grass for my work. I've produced a shapefile which is over 100mbs (s a result of some statistical analysis).

If i convert it to sqlite format (spatially enabled) the data shrinks down to 15 mbs. Which is acceptable for sharing it with email or dropbox.

BUT my colleague is using arcgis 9.3 - will he be able to read the data without any problems?

Comment: You could zip up the shapefile and get similar compression.  7zip will compress it even further.  Probably less hassle than trying to get ArcGIS 9.3 to read a SQLite database.

Comment: so basically that's a "no arcgis 9.3 can not read sqlite data"?

Comment: S-FTP and zipping the files with a higher compression (winzip has this option) would be a solution - best of the ftp free bunch is  filezilla http://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that to do this using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 (or 10.0 or 10.1) the simplest, but expensive, option would be to use the [Data Interoperability extension](http://www.esri.com/library/fliers/pdfs/data-interop-formats.pdf).

However, using [ArcGIS Desktop 10.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//019v0000001w000000) (or later) with no extensions ...

> You can connect from ArcGIS to an SQLite database to create maps and
>   perform spatial analysis on your data.
>
> You connect directly to the SQLite database file from your ArcGIS
>   client.
>
> To store and work with spatial data, you must have either the Esri
>   ST_Geometry type or SpatiaLite installed in your database. You can use
>   the **CreateSQLiteDatabase** ArcPy function to create an SQLite database
>   with either of these spatial data types.

Answer (score 5):

You can install the [Open Source ArcGIS OGR Workspace plugin from AmigoCloud](https://github.com/RBURHUM/arcgis-ogr) that will give ArcMap read access to spatialite and a whole bunch of other formats. It is free. Let me know if you want to test the binaries - I already have some people doing that with success. They only work with 10.1 at the moment since that is the only ArcGIS version I have access to. It should compile fine on 9.3 though.